# Issue with executing batch file(in the User folder) using java

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, process

I am executing a batch file (placed in the User's folder) using below code :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/myapp/bin/dashboard.bat");
OR
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(System.getProperty("user.home") +"/myapp/bin/dashboard.bat").start();
```

dashboard.bat run some jars which has UI interface contains :

```
@echo off
TITLE MyApp Console
if exist %APP_HOME% goto checkuserdata
set APP_HOME=C:\Users\<UserName>\myApp

:checkuserdata
if exist %APP_USERDATA_DIR% goto setuserdatadir 
set APP_USERDATA_DIR_TMP=%APP_HOME%\userdata
goto startapp

:setuserdatadir
set APP_USERDATA_DIR_TMP=%APP_USERDATA_DIR%

:startapp
set POI_JARS= .. // Path of some jar file inside the APP_HOME
set JAVAX_MAIL_JARS= ..  // Path of some jar file inside the APP_HOME
set C3P0_JARS= ..  // Path of some jar file inside the APP_HOME
set APPLET_JARS= ..  // Path of some jar file inside the APP_HOME
set APP_CLASS_PATH= ..  // Path of some jar file inside the APP_HOME


java -version
java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -Djava.util.logging.config.file=%APP_USERDATA_DIR_TMP%\config\log.properties -classpath %APP_EXT_CLASS_PATH%;%APP_CLASS_PATH% net.ui.Dashboard "%APP_HOME%" "%APP_USERDATA_DIR_TMP%"
pause
```

after executing the dashboard.bat in TaskManager process get started but we are not able to get UI interface (i think it run as background process - not sure).

But if we move the dashboard.bat to some other location [other than C drive(OS drive)] and then if we run the batch file from java then it works fine.

please suggest any other way to achieve this or tell me where I am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters, don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: @fge I used that also but no luck.

Comment: Do you have ever executed just __set__ in a command prompt window and looked on all the standard environment variables output with their values? `set "APP_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\myApp"` would be better as this works also on Windows XP and on Windows installations with user profiles directory not located in `C:\User`. And applications should use directory referenced with `%APPDATA%` for user account specific application related files, i.e. `%APPDATA%\CompanyName\ApplicationName` or just `%APPDATA%\ApplicationName`. And user profile path can contain a space character requiring double quotes.